# Safari translate(%,%) aliased

Tags: html, css, safari, transform, css-transforms

I would like to translate `div` -50% horizontally and -50% vertically. My CSS looks like

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

It is working in Firefox 36, Chrome and Opera - translates it and font with images are antialiased. However, when I view it in the Safari 8 there is the font and images aliased.
I have tested some workarounds like:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
```

or

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

or

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

But none of them worked in Safari 8 when using `%`. When using `px` instead `%` it is working well in Safari, too.

Comment: thats strange safari 8 fully supports `transform` http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: There seems to be an issue with white space try `-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

Comment: @Persijn thanks for your advice, but not working - still not antialiased

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-webkit-animation-delay` or add css class to html when window